# RemoteNotifications methods not being hit

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to simply set up push notifications for an Xamarin iOS app. I have made sure I am using a provisioning profile that has the necessary permissions (enabling push notifications in the iOS developer portal). I have verified I am using said provision profile in my app. In my AppDelegate, in FinishedLaunching method, I am executing the following code:

```
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                               UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                               new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
        }
```

I can successfully see the prompt which asks the user if they want to allow push notifications. The issue here is, when I tap on `Allow`, neither of the following overriding methods get hit:

`RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` 
`FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications`

I have also verified, that in my iOS project settings, I have `Enable BackgroundModes` checked as well as the `RemoteNotifications` checked.

Has anyone had any issue with this, and if so, how did you solve?

Comment: Are you by any chance testing it on simulator? On simulator it silently fails, but in reality it's not supported and should at least throw an error, but who am I to tell.

Comment: Good question, but no. I am using my device.

Comment: Are you on ios 10? There were some [changes](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-the-ios-10-notification-framework/)

Comment: I will look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I feel stupid.

So it turns out that `Xamarin.Forms` can be debugged via breakpoints even if your solution config is set to `Release`. But platform specific code cannot be debugged via breakpoints if your solution config is set to `Release`. Setting it to `Debug` fixed it. I just never though about that given that you can debug breakpoints on release in `Xamarin.Forms`.